When creating a new expo app npx create-expo-app ToDoListApp, for some reason no App.js file gets installed after running npm install
So I am just trying it the Ios simulator and made a quick ToDoList app using GPT to get a sense on how React Native works since I am trying to learn. I tried using this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ny7ZWVt3ymo
but when I run the command and look at the folder, I don't see App.js anywhere. When I run the simulator it seems that i loads stuff from /app/(tabs)/ index.tsx and not App.js
Not sure what is happening and I was hoping understand why is that happening? is it some kind of new update?

I don't understand the downvote. Experiencing the same and would like to understand, too.

The best way to create blank app is to use npm init  like this npx react-native init ProjectName. This will create a new empty project with all the nedeed files !

create another project but use this npx create-expo-app MyApp --template to specify JavaScript
